# Shutdown domain PC's in bulk ASYNCHRONOUSLY

Tags: domain, vbscript, shutdown, bulk-action

I am using psshutdown to turn off list of computers, but it seems ages to shutdown a list of 50+ PC's. It's shutting down them one by one, not all of them at the same time.

Is there any program or script to shutdown all PC's asynchronously, not one by one, even if i am feeding list?

Like some vbs script to create multiple instances of psshutdown.

Thanks.

Comment: `Is there any program or script to shutdown all PC's synchronously, not one by one, even if i am feeding list?` - Probably.

Comment: Maybe you know one and could name it?

Comment: You might want to look at SaltStack https://saltstack.com/community/

Comment: shutdown /I opens a Remote Shutdown Dialog you can add PCs to and that should do it. You could also script a batch file to use PSEXEC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a Powershell Workflow...

```
#Requires –Modules PSWorkflow

workflow Shutdown-PCs
{
   $computers = 'computer01','computer02','computer03','computer04'
   Foreach -parallel ($computer in $computers)
   {
        Stop-Computer -PSComputerName $computer -Force -Verbose

    }
}

Shutdown-PCs
```